# jquery value outputing into if statment

Tags: jquery, output

Im taking value from input element and trying to insert into if statement.
how can I output the value ?

```
$( "#vote_description" )
  .click(function() {
    var value = $( this ).val();
    var val2 = value.lenght;
  })

if(  value from jquery function   >=10){
```

Comment: The question is unclear.

Comment: Your issue has to do with `scope` in Javascript. Your `value` variable is not visible outside your callback function, so that's why it doesn't have any value in your if-statement condition.

Answer (score 0):

declare your variable out side the function

```
var val2;

$( "#vote_description" )
  .click(function() {
    var value = $( this ).val();
    val2 = value.lenght;
  })

if( val2 >=10){
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the variable globally. To do this create var `value` and `val2` outside from the function. Then, when you call the function the variable takes the new value and you can put them into an `if` statement or where you want.

Try this:

```
var value=0;
var val2=0;
$( "#vote_description" )
  .click(function() {
    value = $( this ).val();
    val2 = value.lenght;
  })

if(  value from jquery function   >=10){}
```